# "Hello, world" com Wish TCL/TK, como alterar texto de um widget?

Tags: tcl

Estou com dificuldades em entender o funcionamento do programa `wish`, para fazer um bom e velho "Hello, World".

Para quem não conhece o que é o `wish`, ele é um interpretador de TCL pronto para fazer interfaces gráficas em TK. Você programa em TCL, cria seus *widgets* e os posiciona na tela.

Por exemplo, para fazer um botão que imprime `Hello World` no console (com *shebang* e tudo):

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish

button .submit -text "Click Me" -command { puts "\nHello World" }
pack .submit
```

Na primeira linha, criamos um botão identificado como `.submit`, com o dizer `Click Me` que, quando clicado, executa o comando TCL para imprimir no console `Hello World`.

Em seguida, mandamos por o *widget* denominado `.submit` no pacote de coisas da tela.

Veja funcionando:

[image: wish hello]

Até aqui, consegui fazer um "Hello, World" no console, mas não na tela. Gostaria de alterar o texto de uma label, ou até mesmo do próprio botão, para "Hello, World". Tentei alterar o comando do clique para

```
{ puts "\nHello World";  button .submit -text "Hello" }
```

porém... sou saudado com a seguinte mensagem:

[image: Erro, window name "submit" already exists in parent]

> Erro, window name "submit" already exists in parent

que em tradução livre seria:

> Erro, nome de janela "submit" já existe no pai

Ou seja, simplesmente chamar o `button .submit` tenta criar *novamente* um botão chamado `.submit`

Consegui por uma label na tela com uma ligeira variação:

```
{ puts "\nHello World";  label .teste -text "Hello"; pack .teste }
```

[image: label de teste]

Mas clicar no botão de novo vai ocasionar no mesmo erro de que o componente já existe na tela.

Então, minha dúvida é:

- como alterar o teste de um *widget* já colocado na tela?
- ou eu deveria remover e reinserir o componente com as mudanças?

Comment: Qual teste você quer alterar? Se for só alterar o texto do botão, você pode utilizar o comando `configure` com a propriedade `-text`. Exemplo: `{ .submit configure -text "Novo Texto" }`

Comment: @Gomiero nem sabia que poderia fazer o `.submit configure`. Esse seu comentário já seria uma resposta boa o suficiente para mim. Esperando que você transforme o comentário em resposta para poder aceitar e partilhar o conhecimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O widget button tem uma propriedade "textvariable" justamente para isso.
Atribua uma variavel qualquer "v" pelo textvariable,  que irá receber o novo texto,  e toda vez que você alterá-la o texto do botão vai se alterar também.

```
button .b -textvariable v -text "Click-me" -command {set v "Hello Word!"}
pack .b
```

Comment: Essa alternativa é muito mais direto ao ponto do que a anterior. Não que a anterior não funcionasse, mas a sua parece muito mais idiomática e usando as capacidades do TCL/TK do que ficar alterando o texto com `configure`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode alterar o texto (ou qualquer outra propriedade) do *widget*, com o comando `configure`, indicando a propriedade que será alterada e o novo valor.

Exemplo:

```
button .submit -text "Click Me" -command { 
     .submit configure -text "Novo Texto"
     .submit configure -fg firebrick
  }
```

Neste exemplo, ao clicar no botão `.submit`, as propriedades `-text` (texto do botão) e `-fg` (cor do texto) são alteradas para "Novo Texto" e *firebrick*, respectivamente.

Referência (em inglês): [Widget - Configure](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ItclCmd/itclwidget.htm#M24)

Comment: Excelente resposta! E muito obrigado pela referência

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado De nada!! :)